# Why is this div inheriting a width of 900px?

Tags: css

There is only one relevant place that I set a div width to 900 px and it is multiple elements up the DOM on a div called `#Ba`.  I know that this is where it is getting it from.

What I want it to do is simply take on the width of the elements it contains.  The div is called `#mi_control`.

This inheritance covers nearly me entire DOM tree, so I'll just post the element and its children.

```
<div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
  <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Foo &copy; </p>
  <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
  <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
  <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
  <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
</div>
```

I want `mi_control` to have a width equal to it's child elements.

One solution is posted here but I'm not sure it is relevant - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's a div and, by default, all divs are block level and thus 100% wide of their parent.

If you add `display:inline-block` it will shrink-wrap as much as possible.

```
#mi_control {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    top: 220px;
    left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It's one way...floating does the same. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)